# xml elements in elements to python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml

i'm trying to convert the xml data into pandas dataframe.
what i'm struggling is that i cannot get the elements in the element.

here is the example of my xml file.

i'm trying to extract the information of

-orth :"decrease"

-cre_date:2013/12/07

-morph_grp -> var type :"decease"

-subsense - eg: "abcdabcdabcd."

---

```
<superEntry>
    <orth>decrease</orth>
    <entry n="1" pos="vk">
        <mnt_grp>
            <cre>
                <cre_date>2013/12/07</cre_date>
                <cre_writer>james</cre_writer>
                <cre_writer>jen</cre_writer>
            </cre>
            <mod>
                <mod_date>2007/04/14</mod_date>
                <mod_writer>kim</mod_writer>
                <mod_note>edited ver</mod_note>
            </mod>
            <mod>
                <mod_date>2009/11/01</mod_date>
                <mod_writer>kim</mod_writer>
                <mod_note>edited</mod_note>
            </mod>
        </mnt_grp>
        <morph_grp>
            <var type="spr">decease</var>
            <cntr opt="opt" type="oi"/>
            <org lg="si">decrease_</org>
            <infl type="reg"/>
        </morph_grp>
        <sense n="01">
            <sem_grp>
                <sem_class>active solution</sem_class>
                <trans>be added and subtracted to</trans>
            </sem_grp>
            <frame_grp type="FIN">
                <frame>X=N0-i Y=N1-e V</frame>
                <subsense>
                    <sel_rst arg="X" tht="THM">countable</sel_rst>
                    <sel_rst arg="Y" tht="GOL">countable</sel_rst>
                    <eg>abcdabcdabcd.</eg>
                    <eg>abcdabcdabcd.</eg>
                </subsense>
```

---

and i'm using the code

```
df_cols=["orth","cre_Date","var type","eg"]
row=[]
  
for node in xroot:
  a=node.attrib.get("sense")
  b=node.attrib.get("orth").text if node is not None else None
  c=node.attrib.get("var type").text if node is not None else None
  d=node.attrib.get("eg").text if node is not None else None
  
  rows.append({"orth":a, "entry":b,
               "morph_grp":c, "eg" : d})
  
 out_df= pd.DataFrame(rows,colums=df_cols)
```

and i'm stuck with getting the element inside the element
any good solution for this?
thank you so much in advance

Comment: Please include all `import` lines to know your working modules.

Comment: Post a **VALID** xml doc and show how the DF look like.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about what you want, here is an approach using XPath.

I'm assuming you will be iterating over multiple XML files that each have one superEntry root node in order to generate a DataFrame with more than one record.
Or, perhaps your actual XML doc has a higher-level root/parent element above superEntry, and you will be iterating over multiple superEntry elements within that.
You will need to modify the below accordingly to add your loop.

Also, the provided example XML had two of the "eg" elements with same value.  Not sure how you want to handle that.  The below will just get the first one. If you need to deal with both, then you can use the findall() method instead of find().

I was a little confused about what you wanted from the "var" element.  You indicated "var type", but that you wanted the value to be "deceased", which is the text in the "var" element, whereas "type" is an attribute with a value of "spr". I assumed you wanted the text instead of the attribute value.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

df_cols = ["orth","cre_Date","var","eg"]
data = []

xmlDocPath = "example.xml"
tree = ET.parse(xmlDocPath)
superEntry = tree.getroot()

#Below XPaths will just get the first occurence of these elements:
orth = superEntry.find("./orth").text
cre_Date = superEntry.find("./entry/mnt_grp/cre/cre_date").text
var = superEntry.find("./entry/morph_grp/var").text
eg = superEntry.find("./entry/sense/frame_grp/subsense/eg").text 

data.append({"orth":orth, "cre_Date":cre_Date, "var":var, "eg":eg})

#After exiting Loop, create DataFrame:
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df_cols)
df.head()
```

Output:

```
    orth    cre_Date    var eg
0   decrease    2013/12/07  decease abcdabcdabcd.
```

Here is a link to the ElementTree documentation for XPath usage: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support